# Sci-fi series about "mutant" sub-race with gold skin and eyes

Tags: story-identification, books, mutant

This was a series of books pertaining to a sub-race of humanity called "mutants" with gold skin and eyes? It was popular around the same time frame as Octavia Butler. It wasn't *X-Men*.

Comment: Google query, "Gold Skinned Mutants" returns...Philip K. Dick story “The Golden Man,” a gold-skinned mutant who can see the future is hunted down by government agents wanting to harness that power.  Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Man.  That reference is to a single, gold-skinned mutant though.

Comment: Or, https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1705158.The_Mutant_Season: Starting in the 1400s, children with gold-colored eyes and strange abilities--telepathy, telekinesis, and the like--began to be born into the world.

Comment: The Golden Man ends up impregnating all the human females around so soon there will be a subrace of Golden People.  Not a book series though AFAIK

Comment: I seem to remember that some of "Cordwainer Smith's" (Paul Linebarger) Instrumentality stories had golden skinned people

Comment: It was mutant season. Thanks sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Sam's comment above, and David's confirmation, this is *[The Mutant Season](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1705158.The_Mutant_Season)* by Karen Haber and Robert Silverberg, released in 1990:

[image: *The Mutant Season*]

> Starting in the 1400s, children with gold-colored eyes and strange abilities--telepathy, telekinesis, and the like--began to be born into the world. For centuries, these "mutants" kept themselves hidden for fear of persecution, but in the latter part of the 20th century, they found more and more acceptance among the rest of society. But now, in 2017, the murder of a prominent politician brings the "mutant" population into direct conflict with "normal" people, and the outcome will forever change the planet.

Confirmation:

> It was mutant season. Thanks sam – David Myers 10 hours ago

Comment: I can yield this answer to David as needed, but I wanted to be sure there was an answer in the system.